# Error getting in Visual Stdio Code during run python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Code is:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

button1 = Button(window, text = 'Execute')
button1.grid(row = 0, column= 0)

input1 = Entry(window)
input1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

text1 = Text(window, height = 1, width = 20)
text1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

Error is:

```
[pylint] F0002:<class 'RuntimeError'>: generator raised StopIteration
```

the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPHX0.png) is also attached for reference.

Comment: pip install --pre -U pylint astroid

Comment: Run it without Visual Studio?

Comment: The code works perfectly in my Linux machine, from the terminal, maybe you should try the CMD in Windows, and see whether it works.